# st_intersection between polygons and points

Tags: r, gis, polygon, r-sf, points

I have two sf objects that I would like to intersect, but I can't.

1. `D_sf` has 633 observations and has a POLYGON geometry
2. `Temp_points_sf` has  11266 observations and has a POINT geometry.

My aim is to average out the multiple points that are found in each single polygon geometries.
Here you can find the full code:

```
# Code for one layer of the grib (layer=days temperatures)
N_days = 365

#Create veCtors with the dates to label later data
Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by="days")

# Import Temp 2018 ore 13 era5 skin temperature
file <- "Data/Raw/Temperature/adaptor.mars.internal-1602054929.639875-5679-35-5d951960-05b1-4e42-8f0f-b42b0b69ad7f.grib"
GRIB<- stack(file) 

# Convert D in a spatial polygon dataframe
D <- as_Spatial(D)

# Begin the dataset (just index now, then attaChes every variable at eaCh iteration). 
Average_temperatures_URAU <- data.frame(D@data[, 1])
colnames(Average_temperatures_URAU)[1] <- "URAU_CODE"

# take the ith layer of the file (first day of 2018 to last day of 2018)
Grib_layer <- GRIB@layers[[1]]

# original data are Centered on the paCifiC. Use the rotate() funCtion to Center on europe, in this way it is not Cut
Grib_layer <- rotate(Grib_layer)

# Change the crs of D to use it as a mask in the Cycle
D2 <- spTransform(x = D, CRSobj = crs(Grib_layer))

# Extract D from world map
masked <- mask(x = Grib_layer, mask = D2)
cropped <- crop(x = masked, y = extent(D2))

# Transform the raster file to be a point one
layer_cropped  <- rasterToPoints(cropped, spatial="TRUE")

# Go baCk to normal Coordinates
layer_cropped_points <- spTransform(x = layer_cropped, CRSobj = crs(D))

# Change name
names(layer_cropped_points) <- "Temperature"

# Intersection of D and temps, sf is faster so we convert them
D_sf <- st_as_sf(D)
Temp_points_sf <- st_as_sf(layer_cropped_points)

#as often the case the geometry is invalid due to small irreg. make it valid
D_sf <- st_make_valid(D_sf)
Intersection_D_temp_sf <- st_intersection(D_sf, Temp_points_sf)

Intersection_D_temp_sf <- Intersection_D_temp_sf[, c("URAU_CODE", "Temperature" )]

# Sorting Now we Can average out the multiple points in the areas (apply mean by group)
yyy <- ddply(Intersection_D_temp_sf, .(URAU_CODE), summarize, Avg_temp=mean(Temperature))

# Change the name of the variable to "Avg_temp_Month_Year"
yyy_sorted <-  yyy[order(as.numeriC(yyy$URAU_CODE)),] 


# Convert to Celsius
yyy_sorted$Avg_temp <- yyy_sorted$Avg_temp - 273.15


# Add the dates from the veCtor dates to the variable name
colnames(yyy_sorted)[2] <- as.character(Date[i])

# AttaCh the iterations' month to the whole dataset
Average_temperatures_URAU <- merge(Average_temperatures_URAU, yyy_sorted, by = "URAU_CODE")

print(i)
gc()
```

However, the code takes forever to run. When I checked line by line, I found that the function `st_intersection`is the one that blocks the code. How can i fix this?

Comment: We can't run this without your data, and without your data we can have no idea what's going on. Currently all we know about your data is there are 633 polys and 11,000 points.

Comment: Impossible to load a significant portion of my dataset with `dput` because geometries are multipolygons and with just three observations I exceed the text limit for the post. For this understandable reason, this website is full of questions regarding polygons and the sf package without data attached to it.

Comment: Sample data can be uploaded to file sharing sites like Dropbox, this website is full of questions with data attached to them via such things.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I was able to fix this by myself.

I replaced a large portion of the `if` statement leading to the `st_intersection` function with a simple `raster::extract` function. This correction not only speeded up the process, but also produced the expected results.

As a conclusion, it appears that `raster::extract` is more efficient than `sf:st_intersection` in retrieving spatial averages with mulipolygons geometries as masks.

Comment: They're doing completely different things. st_intersection is working at the vector level, raster::extract is doing raster sampling.

Answer (score 0):

It was taking me forever to compute the intersection while using st_intersection for two sf polygon data from all over US. I transformed the coordinate for both data to Albers conic (ESPG = 5070) and I was able to get the results in less than a minute. I am not sure how the accuracy will be impacted but for me it still seems to be accurate enough. So may be trying different coordinate system might help.